# Troubleshoot div that won't stretch

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a web page that has several divs embedded and I'm having a problem when a table has too many rows; when it does, the containing div falls short and bottom ones are displayed on top of the background instead.

Any hints on how to troubleshoot this? I've tried setting several attributes to the different divs with no luck?

Comment: Some source HTML and CSS would help us to see your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few things to check:

- Float attributes
- opening     `<div>`and closing `</div>` tags do not overlap with other tags:

Example of wrong way:

```
<tr>
<div>
</tr>
</div>
```

Also, post some code so we can see where we can help.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you've set height: 100% on the div, which would make it the height of the visible page. As Kyle said some more details would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

we certainly need to see the code.. my first idea is that (depending on weather you use float: or not), you need to clear: both a few places.